# Writing prediction results into separate files for each group using 'for loop' in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

I have a Dataframe "c" which has an attribute called 'UNITID'. I have divided the dataframe with respect to different 'UNITID's and run the neural network model on each of the 'UNITID's. Please see coded below for the same. I have labelled them as c1,c2,...cn using the enumerate function and stored in 'c_new'

```
c_count = c['UNITID'].nunique()
c_new={"c{0}".format(i+1):j[1]for i,j in enumerate(c.groupby('UNITID'))}
for i in range(c_count):
    i = i+1
    c_data = 'c'+str(i)
    print("==============================-------{}-------===========================".format(i))
    c_new[c_data] = c_new[c_data].set_index('DATETIME')
    values = c_new[c_data].values
    # Encoding categorical data
    ..
    #Convert Categories in Text into numbers using Label encoder/ OneHotEncoding
    ..
    # split into train and test sets
    ..
    # reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
    ..
    #Scale and Normalize inputs
    ..
    # Deep Neural Network model
    ..
    # fit network
    ..
    # make a prediction
    ..

    #performance metrics: MAE, MSE, RMSE, Rsq
    ...
```

Every time the model is run for each of the UNITID, new prediction results are generated, but my current code only overwrites the results into the same file, with the same file name(makes sense, since that is  how df.to_csv works).

What I want is to write the results into a separate file everytime new results are generated. For every c{i} where i = 1,2.. n. ; the prediction output file for each should be c_out_{i}, like below.

```
i/p file --> o/p

c1 --> c_out_1
c2 --> c_out_2
c3 --> c_out_3
.
.
cn --> c_out_n
```

How can I achieve this?

```
#Write  predictions to file
test_y = pd.DataFrame(test_y) #Actual values
yhat = pd.DataFrame(yhat) #predicted values using the model

test_y.rename(columns= {0: 'Actual value'}, inplace = True)
yhat.rename(columns = {0: 'Pred value'}, inplace = True)

new = pd.concat([test_y, yhat], axis = 1)
#print(('ct'+ str(i)))
new.to_csv('c_out_{i}.csv') #I want to write a different output csv file for each UNITD's prediction;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: filename = "c_out_" + str(i) + ".csv"

Comment: You can also try `new.to_csv('c_out_%s.csv' %i)`

Comment: Thank you @Nightmerker, it works!

Comment: Thank you @Bazingaa, it works!

Comment: @shweta24: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within your for loop add in:

```
new.to_csv('c_out_' + str(i) + '.csv')
```